# How can we change the font-weight of the headers in react material ui table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have tried overwritting the "MuiTableCell-head" but it doesn't work.

```
`used makeStyles to overwrite .MuiTableCell-head`

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  test: {
    "& .MuiTableCell-head": {
      fontweight: 700,
    },
  },
});

 <TableCell className={classes.test} align="left">
   Date
 </TableCell>
```

Comment: Can you share which styles are applied or overwritten in the console? Perhaps you need to add a !important after 700.

Answer (score 1):

your selector `"& .MuiTableCell-head"` compiles to:

`.makeStyles-test-[identifier] .MuiTableCell-head`

However, the MUI class is not attached to a nested element, but the same `th` element your custom class is attached to. What would work instead is:

`"&.MuiTableCell-head"`

The added increase in in specificity is really not required here, though, so you can simply go with:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  test: {
    fontWeight: 700
  }
});
```

Also note the change from `fontweight` to `fontWeight`. These kind of issues are relatively easy to debug by looking at the DOM structure and styles tab in the DevTools.